# android emulator - change screen resolution keyboard disappears

Tags: android, screen

I'm trying to work with an emulator with a particular screen resolution, but when I set the screen parameters to the ones I need, the keyboard disappears. This way I don't have back button, home button..
Any ideas how to solve this problem?
This is what I have set in the AVD manager:
screen resolution: 1024 x 600
keyboard support: yes
accelerometer: yes
abstract LCD density: 160
device ram size: 256

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your screen is not big enough, the keyboard disappears, but you can still use the keyboard shortcuts. The full list is below, but for the home button you can use the "HOME" button on your keyboard while for back you can use "ESC":

```
Emulated Device Key Keyboard Key
Home    HOME
Menu (left softkey) F2 or Page-up button
Star (right softkey)    Shift-F2 or Page Down
Back    ESC
Call/dial button    F3
Hangup/end call button  F4
Search  F5
Power button    F7
Audio volume up button  KEYPAD_PLUS, Ctrl-5
Audio volume down button    KEYPAD_MINUS, Ctrl-F6
Camera button   Ctrl-KEYPAD_5, Ctrl-F3
Switch to previous layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)    KEYPAD_7,     Ctrl-F11
Switch to next layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)    KEYPAD_9,     Ctrl-F12
Toggle cell networking on/off   F8
Toggle code profiling   F9 (only with -trace startup option)
Toggle fullscreen mode  Alt-Enter
Toggle trackball mode   F6
Enter trackball mode temporarily (while key is pressed) Delete
DPad left/up/right/down KEYPAD_4/8/6/2
DPad center click   KEYPAD_5
Onion alpha increase/decrease   KEYPAD_MULTIPLY(*) / KEYPAD_DIVIDE(/)
```